# GCC template : error : expected ',' or '...' before '< ' token

Tags: c++

I'm a new bee to C++.
I'm having below errors when tying to compile below templates example copied from "Essential C++", I simply copied the example on the book.

"error : expected ',' or '...' before '< ' token"
"error : 'vec' was not declared in this scope

I was wondering what could be the problem, could you help spare some time to give a hint? so much appreciate!

'''

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename elemType>
void display_message(const string &msg, const vector<elemType> &vec)
{
    cout << msg;
    for(int ix = 0; ix < vec.size(); ++ix)
    {
        elemType elem = vec[ix];
        cout << elem << ' ';
    }
}
int main()
{
    int size = 10;
    ocnst vector<int> ivec1 = fibon_seq(5);
    if (is_size_ok(size))
    {
        display_message(msg, size);
    }
    display_message(msg, ivec1);
    cout << "Hello world!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

'''

Comment: As a hint about your problem: Where is the symbol `vector` defined or declared?

Comment: Where is `msg` defined in `main`? Where are `display_message`, `fibon_seq`, and `is_size_ok` defined? `display_message` takes a string and a vector as arguments, you pass it a string and an int.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a lot of issues with the code that prevent from compilation:

1. The functions `fibon_seq` and `is_size_ok` are not defined. You have to define them in this file or include them with a `#define` macro.
2. The code appears to be including the `std` namespace. You need to include this with `using namespace std;`, usually at the beginning of the code, after library includes.
3. The variable `msg` is passed as an argument in a function, but it's not defined.
4. This function call `display_message(msg, size);` is being passed the wrong argument. `size` is an integer, but the function expects `vector<int>`.
   5.`ocnst` is a typo. It should be `const`.

Comment: *"include them with a **`#define` macro**"*. You meant **`#include` directive**.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems with your code:

1. `ocnst` should be `const`.
2. Missing `#include <string>`
3. Missing `#include <vector>`

The last one is the likely cause of that particular error.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much for your time and generous help!H
How embarrassed, I did forgot to add
#include  since I copied the code from previous code.
"essential C++" seems a good book that recommend by many ppl. I'm still trying to familalize the language.
if you think there is better material, please give me a piece of advise, Thanks!